# php не вносится значение в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день есть форма:

```
<h2><p><b>Регистрация</b></p></h2>
<form action="ok_reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Ваш логин:<br></label>
<input name="login" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>

<p>
<label>Ваш пароль:<br></label>
<input name="password" type="password" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>


<p>
<label>Ваше имя:<br></label>
<input name="name" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>

<p>
<label>Ваша фамилия:<br></label>
<input name="soname" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>

<p>
<label>Ваше отчетсво:<br></label>
<input name="dadname" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>

<p>
<label>Ваша должность:<br></label>
<input name="position" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>
<p>
<label>Ваша почта:<br></label>
<input name="mail" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>
<p>
Ваше фото:
<input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
</form>
```

На ней, нас интересует только инпут: position
Смотрим далее:
Есть файл обработчик: ok_reg.php
при заносе в БД собственный фильтр говорит, что низя, включал отображения ошибок, ничего нет.
Сообственно в чем проблема:
в БД не заносятся значения именно с инпута position 
весь код уже перелопатил,все перепроверил все работает нормально кроме последнего инпута(position)
Для удобства на всякий случай продублирую все на пастебин
ВОТ ФОРМА:http://pastebin.com/CPgaNPKZ
ВОТ ОБРАБОТЧИК:http://pastebin.com/dYRPhTiU
сам обработчик:

```
 <?php
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

       if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
   {
     echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
     exit;
   }

   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
   } else {
      echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
   }
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) { $name=$_POST['name']; if ($name =='') { unset($name);} }
    if (isset($_POST['soname'])) { $soname=$_POST['soname']; if ($soname =='') { unset($soname);} }
    if (isset($_POST['dadname'])) { $dadname=$_POST['dadname']; if ($dadname =='') { unset($dadname);} }
    if (isset($_POST['position'])) { $position=$_POST['position']; if ($position =='') { unset($position);} }
    if (isset($_POST['mail'])) { $mail=$_POST['mail']; if ($mail =='') { unset($mail);} }
    echo $soname;

// if (empty($login) or empty($password) or empty($name) or($soname) or ($dadname) or ($position) or($mail) )

  //  {
    //exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
 //   }

    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    //
 $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
    //
    $name= stripslashes($name);
    $name= htmlspecialchars($name);
    //
    $soname= stripslashes($soname);
    $soname= htmlspecialchars($soname);
    //
    $dadname= stripslashes($dadname);
    $dadname= htmlspecialchars($dadname);
    //
    $position= stripslashes($position);
    $position= htmlspecialchars($position);
    //
    $mail= stripslashes($mail);
    $mail= htmlspecialchars($mail);

    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
    $name = trim($name);
    $soname = trim($soname);
    $dadname = trim($dadname);
    $position = trim($position);
    $mail = trim($mail);



    include ("configdb.php");//

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин.");

    }

    //$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,soname,dadname,position,mail) VALUES('$login','$password','$name','$soname','$dadname','$position','$mail')");
    //$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (name,soname,dadname,position,login,password,mail) VALUES('$login','$password','$name','$sname','$dadname','$position','$mail')");
    $result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,soname,dadname,mail,position) VALUES('$login','$password','$name','$soname','$dadname','$mail','$position')");

    if ($result2=='TRUE')
    {
    echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a href='index.php'>Вход</a>";
    //echo $soname;
    }
 else {

    echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: 1) про sql-инъекции не слышали? стоит почитать, ваш код никуда не годится 2) запрос из `mysql_query(...)` надо вынести в отдельную переменную и распечатать. После этого смотрите на запрос (возможно, выполняете его ручками в консоли mysql) и смотрите почему не срабатывает запись `position`. Если ваш запрос не обновляет запись - значит вместо кучи кода достаточно будет его одного. Если окажется, что в запросе этого position и нет, значит смотрите где он пропал и задаете вопрос уже по конкретному месту. 3) зачем использовать устаревшее `mysql_query`?

Comment: я бы сначала проверил сам запрос, потом проверил бы наличие нужного значения в `$_POST`, потом проверил наличие `$position` до и после `include ("configdb.php");`. Но самое главное - я бы проверил значение до `$position= htmlspecialchars($position);` и после. Скорее всего именно здесь и косяк, т.к. по [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php): *Если входная строка string содержит неверную последовательность символов в указанной кодировке encoding, то будет возвращаться пустая строка в случае, если флаги ENT_IGNORE или ENT_SUBSTITUTE не установлены.*

Answer (score -1):

как оказалось в mysql просто был пробел перед именем `position`